# How to use SetField in FindOne in MongoDB For C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I use offical C# Driver for mongodb, I want to use SetFields from a FindOne query like Find.

```
var query = Query.EQ("Name", name);
Users.Find(query).SetFields(Fields.Exclude("Password"));
```

Is it possible to do that as FindOne return a actual class instead of mongodb cursor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SetFields` method of MongoCursor.

Method FindOne just wrapper around MongoCursor and internally it looks so:

```
public virtual TDocument FindOneAs<TDocument>() {
   return FindAllAs<TDocument>().SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you want add Exclude Fields functionality to it you can simply add extention method for `MongoCollection` :

```
public static class MongodbExtentions
{
    public static T FindOne<T>(this MongoCollection collection, 
                               params string[] excludedFields)
    {
        return collection.FindAllAs<T>().SetLimit(1)
                                        .SetFields(excludedFields)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 var user = Users.FindOne<User>("Password");
```

Comment: Thx. Just forgot it is opensource.

Comment: Changed to "in"cludedFields since that made more sense than "ex"cludedFields

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about exclusion in findOne.
But instead of findOne, you can better use find with limit 1 .
That would return a cursor, which will ofcourse support exclusion of a field.
Something like :

```
var theCursor = Users.Find(query).SetFields(Fields.Exclude("Password")).SetLimit(1) ;
var myItem = null;
foreach (var item in cursor) {
    myItem = item ;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I have updated the question for more general purpose SetFields