# How to return some of fields when querying document, using official mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver

guys, I want to return some fields(not all) of a document, in javascript, it writes like this:

```
 db.media.find ( {Artist : "Nirvana"}, {Title: 1} ) 
 { "_id" : ObjectId("4c1a86bb2955000000004076"), "Title" : "Nevermind" }
```

but, what's the corresponding code of C# using official C# driver, I 'm so tired of looking 'everywhere', so asked here for help.

Comment: I got it, use: Fields.Slice, and Field.Exclude, thank me

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the fields of the cursor after you call find, either setting them or using the fluent interface.

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> books;
var query = new QueryDocument("author", "Kurt Vonnegut");
cursor = books.Find(query).SetFields(fields);
foreach (BsonDocument book in cursor) {
    // do something with book
}
```

SetFields is shown in action in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6593345/121495