# Limit mongodb collection to 1 row

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using mongodb with c# driver, and I would like to limit my MongoCollection to maximum 1 row. How do I do that ?

Comment: Just be careful with your code. Mongo won't enforce this sort of rules.

Comment: You'd either have abstract this so that a query like function adds the limit onto all normal queries or add it manually each time. You could also try the findone method: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-FindOneandFindOneAsmethods

Comment: Do you want to only store maximum of one row?  Or store many but only return always maximum of one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the collection itself to one row, you could use a [capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) with `max: 1`.

```
db.createCollection("mycoll", {capped:true, size:100000, max:1});
```

Comment: And if I want to use the get collection ?

Comment: @Lironess Not sure I understand your question.  You use a capped collection using the same APIs you use for a non-capped collection.

Comment: @Lironess do you mean you want to get only one row, as in `limit`?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged as mongodb-csharp, FindOneAs or SetLimit may be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6593345/284598